# Double slit experiment with separate light sources?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Hi I'm stuck on a conceptual question I am working on which has frustrated me as I'm not sure I still understand this topic but essentially the question is asking:

You complete a Youngs double slit experiment and observe a good interference pattern. Out of curiosity you now use two separate light sources instead of one to illuminate the double slit. Would you observe any changes to the intereference pattern and explain why ?

I think the two light sources would have no phase relation with eachother so there would be no visible interference because they do not interfere. I don't know if this is right though and would prefer a better explanation.

Thank you for any help

Comment: This is basically what would happen, no interference as such

Comment: There would be interference, but the phase difference between the two sources is not constant, and would be charging so fast that you won't be able to observe the pattern.

Comment: I'm still confused what do you mean by charging so fast ?

Comment: If the two sources are separated a certain distance, you will get two superimposed interference patterns. The two slit experiment do not change in essence.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand all 3 of the answers are different to some extent im really confused ?

Comment: I would say that you can compute the interference independently for each source. So you would have two superimposed interference patterns. If the two sources are at the same point (imagine you can do this) then you would get the same interference pattern as with just one source, but brighter.

Comment: I don’t think the two sources interact because there is no coherence. I mean you can add amplitudes for each source separately, and then add both resulting amplitudes. So if both sources are at the same point as I said you would add slit 1 and slit 2 for source 1 and find a pattern, then the same pattern for source 2 and now you add these two amplitudes and the pattern doesn’t change its shape.

Comment: Can light from each source reach both slits? Or does source 1 only illuminate slit 1 and source 2 only illuminate slit 2?

Comment: @PM2Ring Obviously the latter. This is exactly where MBolin's confusion comes from.

Comment: @Layla This is very simple.Photons don't interfere with each other. Each photon interferes only with itself.

Comment: @safesphere Obviously the 2 scenarios are different, but I'm asking Layla to clarify the question. So unless you're a mind reader, your answer is irrelevant. ;)

Comment: @Lyla Yeah, It was a typo. I meant 'changing' not 'charging' in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the original geometry of Young's experiment, [shown here](http://www.physics.louisville.edu/cldavis/phys299/notes/lo_interference.html):

[image]

To get a coherent source, one uses as single slit which allows only inphase waves to be transmitted, the rest are reflected back. So you would force coherence even if there were two different sources behind the first slit on the left.

Lasers have coherent beams,so the first slit can be omitted

[image: laser]

so using light from two lasers would do for your experiment. The result would be that each laser would have its own interference pattern, [as seen here](https://cse.wwu.edu/physics/two-slit-interference-two-wavelengths-laser-pointers) with blue and red lasers.

[image: two laserdbls]

It is evident if they overlap that there would be no obvious interference.

Now if you took two **different** lasers of the same frequency and by some clever mirror arrangements created one beam, would there be interference registered? I would say not, because of the phase differences between the two components, unless you passed the beam through the single slit as in the original Young experiment, i.e. force it to be coherent.

Comment: Running the beams together first through a single slit will do nothing for the mutual *temporal* coherence of the two beams.  There would still not be a visible fringe pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Recall all of your calculations for the double slit experiment. These started from assuming that the light at each slit was in phase. You now have no phase relation between the two slits, and as such none of your calculations matter. The light is out of phase and does not interfere.

Answer (score 0):

The interference will always be because the total field at a point $x$ is determined with all sources: $\square A\propto j$. Another thing is time stability of the interference picture. It really depends on time correlation of phases of different sources.