# Should two laser pointers always shine a point on the screen with same intensity?

Tags: waves, laser, interference, coherence

Lasers are coherent beams so they can be totaly cancelled out if applied a source out of phase of 180 degrees. So the question is simple... do two different coherent lasers of same luminosity when pointed at a point sometimes produce a more destructive and sometimes a more constructive interference depending just on timing when they are switched on in that way that the light beams sometimes start its journey out of phase or in phase to each other? Important:the distances to the point on the screen are equal.

Comment: It's not based on the timing when they're switched on. The frequency may be slightly different between the two laser pointers, so the interference pattern will keep changing. Hypothesis: it will change so quickly that you can't see the pattern and it just looks like the dot is twice as bright.

Comment: @user253751: Googling, the coherence length of lasers varies a lot, but it looks like for your standard laser it won't be longer than 300 m. Light travels at 300 million m/s, so the interference pattern will change on the scale of a microsecond.

Comment: Also [Double slit experiment with separate light sources?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478366/double-slit-experiment-with-separate-light-sources)

Comment: @JohnRennie Please note that this my question is a liter variant of the next question: what should be the intensity of let say red sulight on Earth at a discrete point if all beams of red light arriving at that point were all in phase(ideal case) and not with a gauss distribution of phases of all that different beams?

Comment: if a laser is not coherent with itself after one microsecond, how is it ever going to be coherent with a different laser?

Comment: @KrešimirBradvica: Since sunlight doesn't come in "beams", your next question won't have an answer as currently stated. Maybe you should think about it more carefully before posting it.